# How to make it so that when you click on the button again, it hides its menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make it so that when you click on the button again, it hides its menu
The script works so that when opening another "btn", the one that is active is hidden, + if you click outside the menu field, all are hidden.
**How do I make it so that when I click on the active button again, its menu is hidden**

```
<ul class="first_menu">
        <li class="menu_item">
            <button class="menu_btn">1 btn</button>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <ul class="dropdown__list">
                    <li class="dropdown__item">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">1 Подпункт</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown__item">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">2 Подпункт</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown__item">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">3 Подпункт</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
            <button class="menu_btn">2 btn</button>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <ul class="dropdown__list">
                    <li class="dropdown__item">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">1 Подпункт</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown__item">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">2 Подпункт</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown__item">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">3 Подпункт</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
            <button class="menu_btn">3 btn</button>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <ul class="dropdown__list">
                    <li class="dropdown__item">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">1 Подпункт</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown__item">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">2 Подпункт</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown__item">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">3 Подпункт</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

```
.first_menu {
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
.menu_item,.dropdown__item {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.menu_btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 25px;  
    background-color: black;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.dropdown {
    transition: all 1s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    background-color: black;
}
.dropdown__item {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.dropdown__link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.active {
    top: 100px;
    transition: all 1s;
    transform: translateY(-30%);
}
```

```
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.menu_btn')
btn.forEach(function(item, i){
    item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let currentBtn = e.currentTarget; 
        let nextElemt = currentBtn.nextElementSibling; 
        document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown.active').forEach(function(item, i) { 
            item.classList.remove('active')
        })
        nextElemt.classList.add('active')
        const menuOff = document.querySelector('.first_menu');
            document.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
            const click = e.composedPath().includes(menuOff); 
            if(!click) { 
        nextElemt.classList.remove('active')
        } 
    })
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the associated dropdown's `classList` contains the class that opens the dropdown. If it does, then instead of adding the class, remove it - by using `classList.toggle`.

You should also not be adding an event listener to the document every time there's a click. Add one unconditionally, *once*, on pageload, and check if the click is inside the `.first-menu` to determine whether you need to remove the active dropdowns.

```
const removeActive = () => {
  document.querySelector('.dropdown.active')?.classList.remove('active');
};
for (const button of document.querySelectorAll('.menu_btn')) {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const thisDropdown = e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
    const thisCurrentlyOpen = thisDropdown.classList.contains('active');
    removeActive();
    thisDropdown.classList.toggle('active', !thisCurrentlyOpen);
  })
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.closest('.first_menu')) {
    removeActive();
  }
});
```

```js
const removeActive = () => {
  document.querySelector('.dropdown.active')?.classList.remove('active');
};
for (const button of document.querySelectorAll('.menu_btn')) {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const thisDropdown = e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
    const thisCurrentlyOpen = thisDropdown.classList.contains('active');
    removeActive();
    thisDropdown.classList.toggle('active', !thisCurrentlyOpen);
  })
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.closest('.first_menu')) {
    removeActive();
  }
});
```

```css
.first_menu {
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.menu_item,
.dropdown__item {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu_btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown {
  transition: all 1s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  background-color: black;
}

.dropdown__item {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.dropdown__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.active {
  top: 100px;
  transition: all 1s;
  transform: translateY(-30%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="first_menu">
  <li class="menu_item">
    <button class="menu_btn">1 btn</button>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul class="dropdown__list">
        <li class="dropdown__item">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">1 Подпункт</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown__item">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">2 Подпункт</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown__item">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">3 Подпункт</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu_item">
    <button class="menu_btn">2 btn</button>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul class="dropdown__list">
        <li class="dropdown__item">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">1 Подпункт</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown__item">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">2 Подпункт</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown__item">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">3 Подпункт</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu_item">
    <button class="menu_btn">3 btn</button>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul class="dropdown__list">
        <li class="dropdown__item">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">1 Подпункт</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown__item">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">2 Подпункт</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown__item">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">3 Подпункт</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```